# Prove that $\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=I$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $I \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\forall P$ a partition of $[a, b]$, $L(P, f) \leq I \leq U(P, f)$. Prove that $\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=I$.

Do I have something in there with $L(P, f)=U(P, f)$ and the fact that its integrable? Confused on how to prove this.

Comment: What is your *definition* of "integrable"?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is integrable, you know that$$\sup\{L(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}.$$On the other hand, since, for each partition $P$, you have$$L(f,P)\leqslant I\leqslant U(f,P),$$you know that$$\sup\{L(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}\leqslant I\text{ and that }\inf\{U(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}\geqslant I.$$So, you have two equal numbers, $\sup\{L(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}$ and $\inf\{U(f,P)\,|\,P\text{ partition}\}$, and you know that one of them is smaller than or equal to $I$, whereas the other one is greater than or equal to $I$. So, they are *both* equal to $I$.